# How to filter by author in magit-log?

Tags: magit

In `gitk` you can for example do:

`gitk --author="Some Name"`

Is there a way to show/hide commits by author in the log view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From from the `magit-status` buffer press `l` to open the `magit-log` prefix transient window. Then in the `magit-log` transient window press `-A` to 'limit the commits' to "Some Name". Finally, press `l` again to get the actual filtered log.